# Visual studio can not find a specific reference even though it exists

Tags: reference, sitecore

I am setting up a Sitecore project and when I try to view the website in the Browser I get the following error message:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I understand the error, however, I am not sure why it is being thrown. Since I have included this reference for this project. I want answers of how you have overcome this error. Thanks

Comment: This can happen when the project targets a different version of .NET Framework from the reference.  Say, you add a reference for Own (which targets .Net 4.5 from memory) but your project is targeting .Net 2.0, for example.

Comment: You mention you included the reference, but did you check that the DLL was in your 'bin' folder?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you have the wrong version of the Owin.dll.

Though Sitecore out of the box doesn't depend on the Owin.dll there are some third party modules that rely on this dll particularly when concerning authentication.

I would check that you have not overwritten another version of the dll when you published the Visual Studio project to the website.

If you have binaries that depend on different versions of assemblies you can use Assembly binding redirects to target the correct version of the dll.